# Why QWidget::Mask based on QPixmap works fine, but Bitmap doesn't

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget

Target: make my widget rounded, using `QWidget::setMask`

At first, I want to make a mask using `QRegion`, but later I found that, make a rounded Rect based on region is a not simple way.
So I decided to use `QBitmap`.

```
    QBitmap pixmap(size());//create image
    QPainter pixmapPainter(&pixmap);
    QPainterPath path;
    path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, width(), height(), m_borderRadius, m_borderRadius);//fill rounded rect
    pixmapPainter.fillPath(path, Qt::color1);
    QWidget::setMask(pixmap.mask());
```

Result is:
[image]

But when I change my type to `QPixmap` and add the fill method

```
QBitmap pixmap(size());//
pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);//
QPainter pixmapPainter(&pixmap);
pixmapPainter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
QPainterPath path;
path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, width(), height(), m_borderRadius, m_borderRadius);//
pixmapPainter.fillPath(path, Qt::white);
QWidget::setMask(pixmap.mask());
```

It shows me:

[image]

What's wrong with my first code?

Comment: The only obvious issue is that you never initialize the contents of the `QBitmap`.  Try calling `pixmapPainter.clear()` before the other paint operations.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment by G.M. explains, the bitmap needs to be cleared first.

Also, a widget mask is not really the best choice here. A widget mask is intended for defining the areas where your widget will take mouse input. On most window systems, it will also cause transparency. But the edges will be aliased and not pretty. In order to make a non-rectangular widget with nice edges, one should use translucent widget background and anti-aliased painting - in addition to the widget mask for the mouse input.
This is shown and explained in [Qt's shapedclock example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-widgets-shapedclock-example.html).